# Android How to get current running application process then kill it

Tags: android

How do i get a list of process of running applications , when i press the (Home) button i can se other apps are not closed but running,  how do i programmatically close an app by its package name.

if the package name is found then kill it.

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
            PackageManager pm;
            pm = getPackageManager();
            //get a list of installed apps.
            packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
            Log.i("Not Found",packages.toString());

            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
                //if((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)==1)continue;
                if(packageInfo.packageName.equals("com.chartcross.gpstestplus")) continue;
                am.killBackgroundProcesses(packageInfo.packageName);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/534101/Android/Mobile/current-foreground-activity-service

you can use `getRunningTasks(int)`. But it doesn't work since Lollipop because it's a vulnerability and it's closed now

Comment: Lol why the negative ?  sometimes i just dont understand why people do this when people need help , have they forgoten there was a time they needed help?.

Comment: I'm not negative) I just explained, that the only one possibility is described in the given link. But since Android 5.0 you have no way at all, because it closed by Android developers, to dangerous. But you still can use this method on Android versions lower than 5.0

Comment: I think "a rob" asked why someone downvoted his question without explanation, which indeed is not fair when the question is redacted properly.